# How do I find the AdditionalIncludeDirectories in a Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project object?

Tags: .net, visual-c++, msbuild

I need to programmatically update the `AdditionalIncludeDirectories` deserialized from a VS 2010 `.vcxproj` file.   Where are these definitions stored within the `Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project` object?   I have examples but cannot seem to get a canonical answer.

Comment: You should not have to ever in a million years modify AdditionalIncludeDirectories during a build. Why are you doing that?

Answer (score 0):

That is meta data that is a child of a ProjectItem instance.

ProjectItem:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.evaluation.projectitem?view=netframework-4.7.2

and Metadata is a property off of that:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.evaluation.projectitem.metadata?view=netframework-4.7.2#Microsoft_Build_Evaluation_ProjectItem_Metadata

But why are you modifying that at runtime? Sounds like you are doing something wrong.

Comment: I am not modifying it at runtime.  I need to re-organize a massive directory structure.  The tool I am writing updates all the references within projects within that directory structure based on the known reorganization changes.

Comment: Well, good. Welcome to the club. Been there and done that. But keep in mind, that you can set that property once, in a 'property sheet' (old name) and then just import that set of properties into all your projects. For instance:
<Import Project="..\..\commonstuff.props" />

Answer (score 0):

The answer turns out to be under the `ItemDefinitionGroups` under the `Xml` field of the object.  The information is found nowhere else.  The data is editable, at least to the extent I needed it to be, so that changes are reflected when one serializes the object to disk.
*There is very little documentation of this feature anywhere.*